# Contents from TKinter not being saved to database

Tags: python, database, sqlite, tkinter

I am currently creating a program with a function that allows you to input contents into a database and load those contents into a table through Tkinter. While the table itself doesn't seem to be displayed, the contents within it are not. I have isolated this code in both Tkinter and the database and am still having these issues.

The program that runs the GUI:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from random import randint
import json
import testdatabase

db_actions = testdatabase.DatabaseActions()

window = tk.Tk()  # creates a window

screen_width = window.winfo_screenwidth()  # finds the width of the user's screen
screen_height = window.winfo_screenheight()

width = screen_width  # sets the width and height of the screen
height = screen_height

center_x = int(screen_width / 2 - width / 2)
center_y = int(screen_height / 2 - height / 2)
window.geometry(f'{width}x{height}+{center_x}+{center_y}')  # sets the width, height, and positioning of the window

window.title("Lisi Library")  # sets title of window
window.resizable(False, False)  # Prevents the window being resized by both the x and y coordinates


TableView = tk.Frame(width=200, height=200, background='white')              #defines each frame
EditDB = tk.Frame(window, width=400, height=200, background= 'white')

def DisplayTable():
    TableView.pack(fill='both', expand=True, padx=0, pady=0)

    def DataTable():
            def View():

                for row in db_actions.GetAllStudents():
                    print(row)
                    tree.insert("", tk.END, values = row)


            tree = ttk.Treeview(TableView, column=("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"), show='headings')

            tree.column("#1", anchor='center')

            tree.heading("#1", text="Number")

            tree.column("#2", anchor='center')

            tree.heading("#2", text="First name")

            tree.column("#3", anchor='center')

            tree.heading("#3", text="Surname")

            tree.column("#4", anchor='center')

            tree.heading("#4", text="Class")

            tree.pack()

            View()
    DataTable()
    window.mainloop()

def EditDatabase():
    EditDB.pack(fill='both', expand=True, padx=0, pady=0)

    def AddStudent(student_number, forename, surname, class_):
        print(db_actions.db.execute("SELECT * FROM class").fetchall())
        db_actions.create_student(student_number, forename, surname, db_actions.find_class_id(class_))

    def GenerateRandomNumber(number_enter):
        number_enter.delete(0, 'end')
        generated_number = randint(1000, 9999)
        number_enter.insert(0, (generated_number))

    def SwitchToTables():
        EditDB.pack_forget()
        DisplayTable()

    view_tables = tk.Button(EditDB,
                            text="View tables",
                            font=("comic sans", 12),
                            width=20,
                            height=2,
                            borderwidth=2,
                            relief="solid",
                            command=SwitchToTables,
                            bg='white')
    view_tables.place(x=206, y=0)

    add_students = tk.Label(EditDB,
                            text="Add Students",
                            font=("comic sans", 14),
                            bg='white')
    add_students.place(x=(width / 2) - 25, y=100, anchor='center')

    forename = tk.Label(EditDB,
                        text="First Name",
                        font=("comic sans", 12),
                        bg='white')
    forename.place(x=100, y=150, anchor='center')

    forename_enter = tk.Entry(EditDB,
                              font=("comic sans", 12),
                              width=7)
    forename_enter.place(x=195, y=150, anchor='center')

    surname = tk.Label(EditDB,
                       text="Surname",
                       font=("comic sans", 12),
                       bg='white')
    surname.place(x=300, y=150, anchor='center')

    surname_enter = tk.Entry(EditDB,
                             font=("comic sans", 12),
                             width=10)
    surname_enter.place(x=400, y=150, anchor='center')

    YearGroup = tk.Label(EditDB,
                         text="Class",
                         font=("comic sans", 12),
                         bg='white')
    YearGroup.place(x=520, y=150, anchor='center')

    number = tk.Label(EditDB,
                      text="Number",
                      font=("comic sans", 12),
                      bg='white')
    number.place(x=750, y=150, anchor='center')

    number_enter = tk.Entry(EditDB,
                            font=("comic sans", 12),
                            width=4)
    number_enter.place(x=820, y=150, anchor='center')

    def SupplyEnteredNumberValue():
        insert_entry = number_enter
        GenerateRandomNumber(insert_entry)

    gen_number = tk.Button(EditDB,
                           text="Generate student number",
                           font=("comic_sans", 9),
                           command=SupplyEnteredNumberValue)
    gen_number.place(x=950, y=150, anchor='center')

    def set_add_student_parameters():
        forename = forename_enter.get()
        surname = surname_enter.get()
        student_number = number_enter.get()

        AddStudent(forename, surname, student_number, class_)

    add_student = tk.Button(EditDB,
                            text="Add Student",
                            font=("comic_sans", 12),
                            command=set_add_student_parameters)
    add_student.place(x=1150, y=170, anchor='center')

    def ClassDropdown():
        class_options = ["Year R", "Year 1", "Year 2"]

        value_inside = tk.StringVar(EditDB)

        value_inside.set("Select an Option")

        # Create the optionmenu widget and passing
        # the options_list and value_inside to it.
        question_menu = tk.OptionMenu(EditDB,
                                      value_inside,
                                      *class_options)
        question_menu.place(x=617, y=150, anchor='center')

        def return_answers():
            global class_
            class_ = str(value_inside.get())

        submit_button = tk.Button(EditDB,
                                  text='Submit',
                                  command=return_answers)
        submit_button.place(x=613, y=190, anchor='center')

    ClassDropdown()

    window.mainloop()

EditDatabase()
```

The program that uses the database (named testdatabase)

```
import sqlite3
my_conn = sqlite3.connect('general_db.db')
print("Connected to database successfully")
class DatabaseActions:
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = sqlite3.connect('general_db.db') # Open database connection here
        self.setup_tables()

    def setup_tables(self):
      try:

          self.db.execute('''
              CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Class(
                  ClassID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                  Class TEXT
              );''')

          # sql = "INSERT INTO Class(Class) VALUES(?)"
          # self.db.execute(sql, ["Year R"])
          # self.db.execute(sql, ["Year 1"])    #enter first time it's run
          # self.db.execute(sql, ["Year 2"])

          self.db.commit()

          print("Class Table created successfully")

          #####################################################################

          self.db.execute('''
              CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Students(
                  StudentID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                  StudentNumber TEXT,
                  Forename TEXT,
                  Surname TEXT
              );''')
          self.db.commit()
          print("Student Table created successfully")

          ####################################################################

          self.db.execute('''
              CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS StudentClass (
                StudentID INTEGER,
                ClassID INTEGER,
                value,
                PRIMARY KEY (StudentID, ClassID)
              );''')

          self.db.commit()
          print("StudentClass Table created successfully")

      except sqlite3.Error as my_error:
          print("error: ", my_error)

      r_set = self.db.execute('''select name from sqlite_master
            where type = 'table' ''')
      for row in r_set:
          print(row)


    def get_users(self):
        cursor = self.db.cursor()
        sql = "SELECT * FROM Student"
        results = cursor.execute(sql).fetchall()
        return results

    def find_class_id(self, class_):
        cursor = self.db.cursor()
        sql = "SELECT ClassID FROM Class WHERE Class=?"
        results = cursor.execute(sql, [class_]).fetchone()
        return results

    def create_student(self, StudentNumber, Forename, Surname, ClassID):
        cursor = self.db.cursor()

        sql = "INSERT INTO Students(StudentNumber, Forename, Surname) VALUES(?,?,?)"
        cursor.execute(sql, [StudentNumber, Forename, Surname])

        StudentID = cursor.execute("SELECT StudentID FROM Students ORDER BY StudentID desc LIMIT 1").fetchone()

        sql = "INSERT INTO StudentClass(StudentID, ClassID) VALUES(?,?)"
        cursor.execute(sql, [StudentID[0], ClassID[0]])

        self.db.commit()

    def GetAllStudents(self):
        cursor = self.db.cursor()
        sql = "SELECT StudentNumber, Forename, Surname, " \
              "Class FROM StudentClass JOIN Student ON StudentClass.StudentID = Student.StudentID JOIN Class ON StudentClass.ClassID=Class.ClassID"
        results = cursor.execute(sql).fetchall()
        return results
```

Answer (score 0):

Bro, Make a onemore python file and import this file and perform action and see in your terminal and again your program also doesn't save the data into database.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Aman Programmer I just did that and the data does not seem to be saving to the database